# Variable in PHP but not in Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-blade

I've got something weird that I don't understand..

I've dumbed it down to try and figure out whats wrong but.. well I don't get it..

```
<?php 
    $x = "Type1";
    var_dump($x); 
?>

    {{$x}}
```

I've declared a variable in PHP and dumped it to check it's been assigned (I get the right value). But when I try to give this variable out using blade.. I get nothing, it tells me the variable is undefined..

Am I being dumb or missing something?

Help would be appreciated..

EDIT:

So after talking to Abdulkareem Mohammed I tried to dumb it down further and was left with exactly what I have above, I've noticed that the issue is therefore somehow due to the fact that this code is included on another page.

```
@include('Customer.cust_sections')
```

Replacing the include tag with the above code works, even though they should be equivalent (at least to my understanding)

EDIT EDIT:

Turns out... I was just an idiot who forgot the ".blade" in the filename.. there goes 2h of my life on 6 letters..

Comment: what version of Laravel?

Comment: Laravel v 5.3.19
PHP v 5.6.28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all check your blade file extension.

it must have yourfilename.blade.php.

do you miss .blade?

Comment: Good idea to check that! :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to assign a variable to the blade template your either need to define it within the blade template like so:

```
{{ $x = "test" }}
{{ $x }}
```

Or you need to define it in your controller and then pass it to the view

```
$x = "test";

return $response->view('my-blade-template', [
    'x' => $x,
]);
```

I would recommend keeping as much of your logic and assignment of variables in a controller as possible!

Comment: The logic is supposed to be in the controller, when I noticed the error I tried to figure it out by reducing the code and simplifying it again and again until I reached this.  I don't see why Blade wouldn't work with a variable set in pure PHP.. can you explain?

Comment: At the end of the day Laravel is just a facade on top of PHP and your blade templates are all PHP files (`template.blade.php`). It therefor stands to reason that if you escape from template using `{{ }}`, `{!! !!}` or `@php @endphp` you will be able to set and manipulate variables in pure PHP. I would suggest creating a test blade template and then creating a temporary route to display it. Try passing it variables from the controller and let us know what happens.

Comment: So I agree thats it's just a template engine and therefore in the end everything is pure PHP, thats why I didn't understand why it had to be assigned in blade and not in PHP. Created a test blade page and it worked fine, tracked the problem to the code being "included" on an other page. I've made an edit to reflect that.. as to why though, I'm still stuck :D

Answer (score 0):

It should run. I tried copying your code to test it.
Please show the wide document to see if there is any thing else which is make an issue.

Comment: Figured out that its somehow related to the fact that this code is "included" to another (empty for now) page..  I have a "include" on an empty page that includes the code I've attached above now and it fails. but if I replace the include with this code, it works.. @include('Customer.cust_sections', array('x'=>'Type1'))

Comment: You are trying to `echo $var` in include part when you define the var in the main blade. That's it or I'm confused

Comment: That's the point. The include **dosen't** mean that included part and main part are in `same scope`. They are different scopes

Comment: I've tried both approaches. The variable is supposed to be set from the main page but when I was trying to solve the issue, I declared it at the top again to make sure that wasn't affecting anything. in either case, the var_dump works and blade doesn't. I'll edit my post with more details, give me a minute :)

Comment: Ok. waiting you :)

Comment: Don't ask here use comment instead.

Comment: I can't comment yet @PSN

Comment: @Frenchmassacre . The main point is : `@include, @section, @yeild` may be in the same document but they aren't in the same `variable scope`. you have to pass the variable as second argument as array 
**Example** `@include('blade', ["var"=> "val"]`

Comment: @ PSN, not cool to down-vote the most helpful guy on this question.. mostly when he can't comment..
@ Abdul, if I declare the variable in the lowest scope (my above code) the declaration and use of the variable are in the same scope, why would it matter? But anyway, I've tried passing the variable as an argument in the include as you suggested with no luck. Pure PHP displays it and blade still sees it as empty.. this makes no sense to me..

Comment: Never mind about @PSN . May be he doesn't know that I can't comment yet. It's ok at all.About your issue, let me try and give you with example. wait a minute :)

Comment: @Abdulkareem Mohammed Edit your answer and I can upvote your post.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is using `@php` in the blade template. So your code would be:

```
@php 
  $x = "Type1";
  //var_dump($x); 
@endphp

{{ $x }}
```

I've tried it in one blade template, it passes the variable, but it fails on another. I'm rather confused, too.

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one, tried the @php and it didnt change anything, figured out its somehow because the code is "included" if I replace the include tag with my code and it worked, even though that the only thing the include tag imports... I'm confused to say the least :D